# how to clear and activate cell as variables?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to clear and to activate cell by function, but it doesn't works.

```
 Function cts(a) As Range
 If IsEmpty(a.Value) = True Then
     MsgBox ("ok")
 ElseIf IsNumeric(a.Value) = False Then
     MsgBox "non-numeric entry"
     Range("a").ClearContents
     Range("a").Activate
 ElseIf Int(a.Value) = False Then
     MsgBox "integer required"
     Range("a").ClearContents
     Range("a").Activate
 ElseIf a.Value > 5 Or a.Value < 1 Then
     MsgBox "valid values are between 1 and 5"
     Range("a").ClearContents
     Range("a").Activate
 Else:
     MsgBox "ok"
 End If

 End Function
```

the msg is shows up, but not the clear nor the activate.

Comment: `"a"` is not a valid range reference. How do you want to call this function, from the worksheet or within code?

Comment: Is "a" a named range?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, I think you just need to change those statements to `a.ClearContents` and `a.Activate` to achieve what you want.

Comment: a it's the variable within the function - the user's choose.

Comment: Your `Function` isn't returning anything and might as well be a `Sub` procedure. Are you trying to invoke it as a UDF, from a worksheet cell (e.g. `=cts(A1)`)? If so, you can't do that - a UDF takes inputs and computes a value that is returned to the cell that invokes it: it is not alowed to alter other cells or `Activate` anything. Lastly, `Range("a")` should simply be `a` - and `a` should be declared `ByVal a As Range`.

Answer (score 1):

That `a` parameter is a `Range` object - it should be declared as such:

```
Public Function cts(ByVal a As Range) As Range
```

`IsEmpty` returns a `Boolean`; comparing it to a Boolean literal is redundant:

> ```
> If IsEmpty(a.Value) = True Then
> ```

Should be:

```
If IsEmpty(a.Value) Then
```

The expression `("Ok")` is uselessly being evaluated as a `String` value (it's *already* a string literal). [Don't use parentheses when you discard a function's return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56261848/1188513):

```
MsgBox "Ok"
```

`a` being a `Range` object, this:

> ```
> Range("a").ClearContents
> Range("a").Activate
> ```

Probably means to be this (`"a"` isn't a valid cell reference, so `Range("a")` can't be evaluated):

```
a.ClearContents
a.Activate
```

By declaring `a As Range`, you get *IntelliSense* and Ctrl+Space autocompletion for its member calls; in your code it's an implicit `Variant`, so the member calls are all resolved at run-time (and `Option Explicit` can't save you from a typo).

The function isn't returning anything, and it's not clear what `Range` you mean it to return (or why).

If you wanted it to return `a`, you would do it like this:

```
Set cts = a
```

If the procedure doesn't need to return anything, then it should be a `Sub` procedure, not a `Function`.

> ```
> ElseIf Int(a.Value) = False Then
> ```

That `Int` function call will fail with a *type mismatch* error if `a.Value` contains a `Variant/Error` value, because the conditional block hasn't first evaluated whether `IsError(a.Value)` is true; also `= False` is coercing the `Integer` into a `Boolean`, so the expression will wrongly evaluate to `False` when `a.Value` is `0` (because zero is `False`, and any non-zero value is `True`). The `Int` function takes `123.456` and outputs `123`, i.e. it returns the integer portion of the value it's given - *it does not evaluate whether the argument is an integer or not*.

In order to evaluate whether the value is an integer value, you need to first make  sure you're looking at a numeric value:

```
If IsNumeric(a.Value) Then
```

Then compare `Int(a.Value)` with `a.Value` and see if they are the same:

```
    If Int(a.Value) = a.Value Then
```

Make sure you put the `ElseIf a.Value > 5 Or a.Value < 1 Then` check inside the `IsNumeric` case, otherwise that condition too will blow up given an error value, because `Variant/Error` can't be compared to anythign other than an `Error` value.

Comment: i declared "a" byval, and tried a.clearcontents and activate - it's still not working.

Comment: @NoamMarciano `As Range` is the important part. How are you invoking the function exactly?

Comment: not working mean that the message are show up, but the clear and activate hasn't.    Public Function cts(ByVal a As Range) As Range
     If IsEmpty(a.Value) Then
         MsgBox ("ok")
     ElseIf IsNumeric(a.Value) = False Then
         MsgBox "non-numeric entry"
         a.ClearContents
         a.Activate